# Declaring a vector inside a structure and getting error

Tags: vector, structure

Can anyone tell me what does this error mean?
[Error] 'score does not name a type'.
I keep getting this error while compiling and i don't know what it means. Can anyone help me?

```
struct Date
{
int day, month, year; 
}; 


struct Grade
{
    vector<int>score;
    score.resize(6);
};

struct Student
{
bool free; 
long studentID; 
string fname; 
string sname; 
Date DOB, DOE, DOG;
Grade semester1, semester2;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of this line:

```
score.resize(6);
```

You can **only declare**(there are some exceptions like cosntexpr etc.) variables in structure/class declaration.

You should put that line into your Grade constructor:

```
Grade::Grade()
{
    score.resize(6);
}
```

Check [Demo](http://ideone.com/hCodqy)